# Quality control in Seismic Acquisition - How much data is required?

Tags: geophysics, seismology, seismic

When it comes to land or marine acquisition (oil exploration, for instance), I can see from literature that quality control (QC) is performed during the survey to ensure that the seismic traces obtained are not faulty. However, I see contradicting values for the amount of data that is required for QC. In [1], it is mentioned that just around 10 bytes/minute are sufficient. Meanwhile in [2], it is mentioned that the data collected over the entire day is used for QC.

Can someone point me to a good source where I can understand this aspect better?

[1] - http://home.deib.polimi.it/savazzi/articles/06495774mag.pdf (Page 3, second paragraph under 'Shooting-Blind vs Real Time Telemetry Systems)

[2] - http://www.smngc.ru/en/seismic-surveys/quality-control-of-the-seismic-data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a more elaborate literature survey, it turns out that there are two types of quality control that can be performed on seismic data. One is of the acquisition parameters [1], which are just a few bytes per minute. Meanwhile, in [2], the entire data can be screened through QC software before being sent to a central server. This would help report errors in the acquisition process before conducting further sweeps.

Comment: Much appreciated for taking the time to come back and answer your question!  I don't know whether most of the usual answerers around here would know enough about that specific thing to have ever given a useful answer... but that's exactly where it's of great value to leave breadcrumbs for the next researcher on more specific topics like that.  Everyone benefits if more people start doing this, and I hope you continue to do so when useful!  Thanks!

Comment: It's all about building the community! :-)